# Adobe fireworks UI to mobile live preview

Tags: adobe-fireworks, interface-design, windows, mobile-first

I am running Fireworks on Windows 8.1 and I am designing a user Interface for Moto G mobile. Is there any simple way to see live preview in USB connected mobile phone? I don't remember but there is one software for Macs which shows the live preview in mobile. Since that doesn't work on Windows platform I had to find alternative of it. I have learned enough and now I want to have the similar feature for Adobe Fireworks.

Is there any plugin for that?

Comment: have you tried using https://www.adobe.com/au/products/experience-design.html  ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Fireworks-specific plugin, but something like Reflector might get you the mirroring/previewing functionality you are looking for (similar to LiveView for Mac).

[Reflector for Windows/Android](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/win/)